# Networks can't see each other - 2 Routers - 2 Vlans

Tags: networking, vlan

So this is the network setup currently:

[image: Network diagram]

The issue is that None of the IP phones can ping the computers and vice versa. The reason the phones are on the seperate internet connection is so that if we eat all the bandwidth on the EdgeMAX which only have like 20MBPS it doesn't degrade the phones.

Is this going to be possible to have both networks even see each other? I thought it would have been fairly basic... but I feel like i'm missing some core networking knowledge for this setup... possibly in the ability for the TP links ability to see read routing packets through it's LAn ports but I'm a bit clueless.

Any suggestions as to what's doing wrong and how I could go about repairing it?

Comment: Your diagram suggests that your phones are connected directly to your computers. I presume that is incorrect. Maybe you would like to update your image (try wiring diagram)? Are your switches connected? (What you need is basically a router connected to both VLANs; EdgeMAX should do the trick.).

Comment: Do the phones have network and internet connectivity? Do they work? Do the computers have network and internet connectivity? Do they work? If so, why do you care whether or not they can ping each other? Are the routers connected to both VLAN's? If not, how do you expect traffic to be routed between the two subnets?

Answer (score 1):

You Picture left quite some details open.

I have created a new graph

[image: Your current Network]

This describes, what I understand to be your situation.

In this case, assuming,

- you can deploy additional routes to the phones
- your EdgeMax has another Ethernet port free
- you have a spare cable

you could:

- declare a port on SW1 as VLy untagged
- declare another internal network on EgdeMax, using the free ethernet.
- Give the new EdgeMax connection the IP 192.168.2.2
- Connect those two sockets with the spare cable
- Push the additional route (192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.2) out to the phones.
- Configure the EdgeMax to allow traffic to be routed between the 2 internal networks.

That way, you minimize needed changes, and you don't need to redefine LAN1 on the EdgeMax.

In case there has been a misunderstanding concerning your network layout, please take the below attached graphviz source for the above graph, edit it to reflect your situation, and replace your image after compiling the graph source with `dot -Tpng -O -x source.dot`

```
graph ChrisV {
    splines=false
    node [shape=box, margin="0"]
    {PC1, PCn} -- Sw1:n [label="VLx u"]
    WifiAP -- Rt1
    Sw1 -- Rt1 [label="Vlx u"]
    Rt1 -- INet1
    {PH1, PHn} -- Sw2:n [label="VLy t"]
    Sw2 -- Rt2 [label="Vly u"]
    Rt2 -- INet2
    Sw1:e -- Sw2:w [label="Vlx + VLy t", constraint=false]
    WifiAP [label="Wifi AP\n192.168.X.Z"]
    Rt1 [label="EdgeMax Router\n192.168.1.1 LAN\nPu.bl.ic.IP WAN\n192.168.X.Y WifiDMZ"]
    Rt2 [label="TPLINK Router\n192.168.2.1 LAN\nPu.bl.ic.IP WAN"]
    INet1 [label="Internet\n20MBit Ethernet"]
    INet2 [label="Internet\nCrappy ADSL"]
    rank=same {WifiAP -- Sw1 -- Sw2 [style=invis]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will involve setting up "inter vlan routing". You can read an explanation of this concept in the following link: http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/vlan-networks/222-intervlan-routing.html

Another possible solution involves setting up NAT and allowing the devices to communicate over the internet, I don't think this is what you want.

Fox made a great point, can you provide an updated diagram with the type of switches that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some inter-vlan routing. The edgerouter should be able to do this if its from ubiquiti. Create a trunk from your Switch 1 to the interface on the edgerouter and make sure both vlans are part of the trunk.

On the router you must also configure the connected interface as a trunk and create two vlan 'virtual interfaces', one for each vlan. You must assign an IP to each of these virtual interfaces and use it as the gateway address of all your networked devices. You will need to configure your next hop for the phone vlan on the edgerouter to be your seperate internet connection as well.

(The above can be done with physical interfaces on the router, but I personally prefer trunks and virtual interfaces).